# Shorter form for VB.net properties?

Tags: vb.net

One of our source files consists of thousands of examples of properties like this:

```
Friend Property ZipCode() As String
    Get
        Return GetDtaString(R, fldZipCode)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        SetDtaString(R, fldZipCode, Value)
    End Set
End Property
```

R is the row in a text file, fldZipCode is a column.

AutoProperties allow you to use a compact form of get/set when the property maps onto a backing value, but that is not the case here. I've tried various combinations of colons and everything else I could thing of, but it appears that VB.net demands all of this be on separate lines?

Does anyone know of a way to shorten this syntax up?

Comment: Since that isn't a simple property, that's probably as simple as it gets.

Comment: Since it isn't a simple property, I'd almost prefer to see it as two methods in my code so I know that they are processes, not a just a properties holding data.

Comment: @ps2goat - I guess this goes to the divide between property and methods, but in this case I want to say myObject.ZipCode = "12345", which is far nicer that myObject.SetZipCode("12345") - YMMV of course!

Comment: There's no good reason to write that code any way other than how it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it slightly shorter. Note the:

1. Removal of the `()` after the name of the property
2. Removal of the implied `ByVal` on set's Value parameter

Your new property

```
Friend Property ZipCode As String
    Get
        Return GetDtaString(R, fldZipCode)
    End Get
    Set(Value As String)
        SetDtaString(R, fldZipCode, Value)
    End Set
End Property
```

BONUS: If you were working in c#, you could do

```cs
internal String ZipCode { 
    get { return GetDtaString(R, fldZipCode); } 
    set { SetDtaString(R, fldZipCode, value); } }
```

and it being c#, this could all be put on one line, but that might not look very nice...

```cs
internal String ZipCode {get { return GetDtaString(R, fldZipCode); } set { SetDtaString(R, fldZipCode, value); } }
```

Take a look at the [VB.Net Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039) for more information.

Comment: that's just why I asked, I knew there *was* a way to do it in C# so I was wondering if I was just overlooking a way to do the same thing in VB